# How do I filter my Data series by several conditions on a Klipfolio barchart?

Tags: klipfolio

I am trying to setup a **barchart** in **Klipfolio** to show the percentage of answered calls per queue.

My data source (**Calls**) is from Excel, and it has headers, such as **Queue** (**k**:Text), **CallStartTime** (**i**:Text MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss am/pm) and **ToNumber** (**e**:Text), and others). The headers do appear in the first row of the data.

How can I filter it

1.) where hour of day in CallStartTime is between 8 and 16 (note the pm and am in data)

2.) and ToNumber is "(123) 4567-890"

3.) and Queue is "A" or "B" or "C"

to get a percentages for each item from Queue (X Axis) to find out what percentage of calls were answered?

**X-Axis** : contains "@Calls,K:K" which is then filtered by *[Blank]* & "Queue" **EXCLUDE** & **group repeating labels**

**Series** : formatted as **percentage**, aggregation is currently set to **Sum**

I tried the below, where most items give me a blank chart or I only get the full bars with all the entries per queue

```
COUNTALL
(
    AND
    (
        OR
        (
            @Calls,K:K;="A",
            @Calls,K:K;="B",
            @Calls,K:K;="C"
        ),
        
        @Calls,E:E;="(123) 456-7890"
    )
)
```

and

```
COUNTIF
(
    AND
    (
        OR
        (
            @Calls,K:K;="A",
            @Calls,K:K;="B",
            @Calls,K:K;="C"
        ),
        
        @Calls,E:E;="(123) 456-7890"
    )
)
```

and

`IF(@Calls,E:E;="(123) 456-7890",1,0)`

and

`COUNTIF(IF(@Calls,E:E;="(123) 456-7890",1,0) = 1) / COUNTALL(@Calls,E:E;) * 100`

In SQL I would probably do

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN Queue = 'Donations' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*), 2),
        '%'
    ) AS Donations,
    CONCAT(
        ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN Queue = 'Volunteer' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*), 2),
        '%'
    ) AS Volunteer,
    CONCAT(
        ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN Queue = 'Hotline' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*), 2),
        '%'
    ) AS Hotline,
    CONCAT(
        ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN Queue = 'Accounting' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*), 2),
        '%'
    ) AS Accounting
FROM Calls
WHERE ToNumber = '(123) 4567-890'
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, CONVERT(DATETIME, CallStartTime, 0)) BETWEEN 8 AND 16;
```

to get this on Klipfolio seems extremely difficult and frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

In Klipfolio, it's good to think of each series/x-axis/hidden data slot as interrelated. Since you are familiar with SQL, you'll most likely be more comfortable writing function/formulas instead of using [Applied Actions](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/222017088-Using-the-Filter-Group-Aggregate-and-Sort-actions-videos-) for your series.

Your X-axis set-up is already correct. :)

The series set-up needs to be a [LOOKUP()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/216182777-LOOKUP-video-) to ensure the data in your series aligns correctly with the x-axis. This is most likely why you were getting blanks as data was being aggregated in the series, but not aligned to the x-axis. The formula would look like:

```
LOOKUP(&X-axis,
GROUP(SELECT(@Calls,K:K,AND(@Calls, E:E = "(123) 4567-890",BETWEEN(DATE_CONVERT(@Calls,I:I,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a","HH"),8,16))))
COUNTDISTINCT(SELECT(@Calls,K:K,AND(@Calls, E:E = "(123) 4567-890",BETWEEN(DATE_CONVERT(@Calls,I:I,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a","HH"),8,16))))
/
COUNTIF(AND(@Calls, E:E = "(123) 4567-890",BETWEEN(DATE_CONVERT(@Calls,I:I,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a","HH"),8,16)))
```

The format of the datetime may have to be adjusted based on the [Date/Time formats for Klipfolio](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/216182377-How-do-I-use-Date-Time-formats-) as I'm unsure of the exact format based on your description.

Within the LOOKUP(), the [GROUP()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547998-GROUP-GROUPBY-and-COUNTDISTINCT-video-) groups all values that were selected within based on the condition of the time being between 8 and 16 and the ToNumber being = "(123) 4567-890".

The [COUNTDISTINCT()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547998-GROUP-GROUPBY-and-COUNTDISTINCT-video-) will then return a count of the distinct values in the group above, this is why the SELECT() within is identical to the GROUP() above. The LOOKUP() will then accurately align these values to the x-axis.

The COUNTIF() returns the denominator and will divide the values from the LOOKUP() by all records that match the ToNumber or are within the hours of 8 to 16. This will give you your % of calls answered.